# Fake 0 token transaction on BSC

Tags: erc-20, bsc

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x1dc5ad8ac2c8bed505da92cf55ff6116d24054f99b6df794ab833f40ed30f0d0

In this transaction there was 20 fake transactions. BUSD were moved from addresses that do not belong to transaction sender. So the person who created this transaction doesn't have private keys of addresses 0 BUSD were sent from. How is this possible?

Comment: maybe the owners approved this contract   "0xee192bdbc2c5dc8019c1dfca7c88caab74515253" to transfer those tokens. or the those tokens allow transferFrom(anyone , anyone, 0) for some reasons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contracts of those tokens (e.g. [this](https://bscscan.com/token/0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56)) allow transferring 0 Tokens from any account to any other account.

This is possible because the check of transfer and approvement is implemented like this
[image]

`if balance - amountToTransfer is not negative then allow it` and 0 - 0  is not negative

This means

- Account A can send 0 tokens to account B. even if account A has 0 tokens
- Account C can send 0 tokens from any Account to any other Account even without approval.

I'm not sure if it is intended (Probably yes, because it probably does not do any harm). **But the real question is What is the goal  of transferring 0 tokens?**

You can copy the code of the token to [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.js), deploy it and then try it yourself

[image]

Comment: This transaction sends 0 dollars to addresses very similar that owner sends to. Then the owners copy pastes the address and sends tokens to scammer.

Comment: @Baltar if this was the answer to your question, then please mark it as solved :) thanks